# How to hide some groups in the res.users form in Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, security, odoo-8, odoo

I've created a module which adds security data like a new category and some new groups which belong to that category.

What I want now is to go to the configuration of an user and see only these new groups in the tab `Access Rights` (this means hiding the common ones like sale, warehouse, purchase, etc).

I was thinking to do it applying a domain to the field `groups_id` in the xml view, but I'm not even able to get this field from the parent view:

```
<record id="view_users_test_form" model="ir.ui.view" >
    <field name="name">users.test.form</field>
    <field name="model">res.users</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Access Rights']//field[@name='groups_id']" position="after">
            <p>HELLO</p>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Before this code I tried first without `xpath`, only `<field name="groups_id" position="after">`, and then with other combination of `xpath`, but no result.

This field is kind of weird (if you look at it under the developer mode, you'll see things like `in_groups_19` and more), so I don't know if it's going to be possible to modify it the same way as any `Many2many`.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I change the name and id and it works.

Comment: Which way do you get the field `groups_id`?

Comment: i used xpath, like you.

Comment: As I understood, you want to hide all group *Technical Settings*? With fields **in_group_1** - **in_group_n**

Comment: Or you want to hide specific fields like **in_groups_19**, **in_groups_20** etc. and paste something to this place?

Comment: May be you can put groups to a inherit view of this model